# Using Like statement in SQLITE on android studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I have a SQLite database containing informations about cars. I want to sellect cars that are branded BMW.
I have this statement:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " +Note.TABLE_NAME+ " where " + "BRAND" + " like "+ "BMW";
```

The app crashes and logs shows:

```
no such column: BMW (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM adds where BRAND like BMW
```

When i am using this one the app works:

```
 String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " +Note.TABLE_NAME+ " where " + "AGE" + " like "+ "10";
```

How do i use Like with a string after that?

Comment: Are BRAND and BMW both columns in the table?

Comment: BMW is a string literal and should be enclosed inside single quotes, or better passed as a parameter to the sql statement.

Comment: BRAND is a colum and BMW should be the value. I just don't understnad why it works with AGE but not with BRAND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround the value that you are retrieving with single quotes.

Try this instead:

`String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " +Note.TABLE_NAME+ " where " + "BRAND" + " like 'BMW'";`

Alternatively, you don't need to put each word of the query in their own quotes. You could just use:

`String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " +Note.TABLE_NAME+ " where BRAND like 'BMW'";`

Answer (score 0):

For the statement:

```
SELECT  * FROM tablename where BRAND like BMW
```

SQLite considers `BMW` as a column name (which of course does not exist) so the code fails.
It should be:

```
SELECT  * FROM tablename where BRAND like 'BMW'
```

But for the statement:

```
SELECT  * FROM tablename where AGE like 10
```

SQLite does not consider `10` as a column name, because it is a literal value which is implicitly converted to `TEXT`: `'10'` and the code works without problem.